# WordPress CMS Woocommerce plugin cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am new to WordPress and since I created one e-commerce store using woocommerce plugin.
There is some page created by woocommerce plugin called cart, account, checkout, etc.
I already created store and its working fine when I place order for any product with some quantity suppose it is 5 each of $5 and I am going to cart page it is showing total ammount of $25.
but in cart page when I change the quantity of product the total amount is not changing.
So, please somebody help me how I can solve this, I want that instant change in total amount on quantity changing in cart page.

Comment: put some code of your work around

Answer (score -1):

It should be a bug,don't try to write custome code on the plugin here are steps that you can follow :

1. try to deactivate all plugins.
2. If not fixed , try to change your current theme.
3. The last solution is to try new installation of WP And WooCommerce.